# Perform SpriteKit Physics Body Collision/ Contact on touch End

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit

I am having some physics body nodes. Sprite Kit immediately calls didbegincontact method. I want that method should be called when i release the touch so that it may perform actions when click was released instead of calling method immediately causing some action setting problems for me.

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{   NSLog(@"%hhd", _touching);
    if(_touching == NO)
     return;
something here
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
_touching = YES;
 NSLog(@"%hhd", _touching);

}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
_touching = NO;
NSLog(@"%hhd", _touching);
something here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set the global Variable, ie

   ```
   BOOL _touching;
   ```
2. When you touch / release (touches ended and began) you set that var to YES / NO;
3. In the didbegincontact, use something like

   ```
   if(_touching == YES) {
       // what I want to happen when I am touching
   } 
   else {
      // i must not be touching so do this
   }
   ```

**Here is the basic set up - however I think its the game logic thats the issue, maybe think of a different way to solve your problem**

```
@interface XBLMyScene()

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKNode *world;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKSpriteNode *ball;
@property BOOL touching;
@end

@implementation XBLMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    self.world = [SKNode node];
    [self addChild:self.world];

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];

    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointZero toPoint:CGPointMake(500, 0)];

    self.ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    self.ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 40)];
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(200, 300);
    [self.world addChild:self.ball];

    self.touching = NO;

}
return self;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.touching = YES;
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.touching = NO;
}

- (void) didSimulatePhysics
{
if (self.touching) {
    NSLog(@"I am touching");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"I am not touching");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But here is a clarification of the statement "Next time post your code/ideas of what you have tried.": What should i do if i am beginner or stuck with the things that how to do that? How can i post the ideas if i don't know how to do that. I think if had ideas, i shouldn't have posted question here for help. Anyways. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: The solution is not working. If i set it to it to yes, the didbegincontatc is not being called after touch end.

Comment: I have tried exactly same that you are saying. Also used NSLOG statement to see if it is changing values but it is not calling didbegincontact after touch end

Comment: I extremely appreciate your work. But to be true, the code is not working.

Comment: Can you please send me the project that you created so that i may get more clarification where am i wrong. And one thing i want to say i can not set it in viewdidload method. Because its a scene, not view.

Comment: after helping you out, I figured out what you want to make - instead of physics, you could just use CGRectIntersectsRect(shape.frame, shape2.frame)